# How to delete Catalog, Category and SellableItems in Sitecore Commerce programatically?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I need to delete the catalogs from Sitecore Commerce by using code. Is there any pipeline or command?

Comment: Can I ask what is the reasoning behind deleting catalog programatically? What is your business case?

Comment: what commerce version do you have?

Comment: I am using  9.0.1  version now. I am getting the Catalogs from third part source to add in to SXC. While doing development , i need to delete catalogs at some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 9.0.1, you can invoke `IRemoveAllCatalogItemsPipeline` to delete *all* catalogs, categories, and sellable items. You can invoke it using Postman via the `RemoveAllCatalogItems()` API. There are no APIs (controllers/pipelines) for deleting *individual* catalogs.

I believe 9.0.2 introduced UI for deleting sellable items so presumably there are additional pipelines that support that functionality, but I'm not familiar enough with 9.0.2 to help with any details.